# How do I load data from an API into an array in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So last week I started learning AngularJS, only to realize that I'm better off learning Angular 2 instead. After much reading and tinkering with sample apps on Plunker, I'm finally ready to dive into Angular 2. Last week with AngularJS I was able to create a simple app that retrieves data from an API and turns that into a navigation menu. So this week I am attempting to port that code to Angular 2.

I can't say that it was easy, but after much fiddling I found that the reason it was not working was that it was not even pulling the data. Below is my code for the service that pulls the data.

**`./src/app/navigation.service.ts`**

```
import { NavItem } from './navigation.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class NavService {   
    sections: NavItem[] = [];
    categories: NavItem[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
    loadSections() {
        //var headers = new Headers();
        //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.http
            .get('http://localhost:15557/api/navigation/sections/list')
            .map(res => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.sections = data;
            },
            err => this.logError(err),
            () => console.log("Loaded all sections")
        );
    }

    loadCategories(id) {
        this.http
            .get('http://localhost:15557/api/navigation/categories/' + id)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => this.categories = [data],
            err => this.logError(err),
            () => console.log("Loaded categories in section with id " + id)
        );
    }

    logError(err) {
        console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
    }
}
```

**`./src/app/navigation.model.ts`**

```
export class NavItem {
    // I am never going to use int unless I need to do math operations //
    id: string;
    name: string;
    pid: string;
    slug: string;

    constructor(id: string, name: string, pid: string, slug: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.slug = slug;
    }
}
```

**`./src/app/navigation.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavItem } from './navigation.model';
import { NavService } from './navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})

export class NavComponent {
    public section: NavItem;
    constructor(private service: NavService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.loadSections();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this code?

Comment: At first glance, the code seems fine. I would suggest using the Chrome Dev Tools to look at your Network traffic to see what response you are getting. Also, I would `console.log` the `data` response in your subscribes to find out what's really happening. Also, make sure you're actually using Angular 2. In Angular 4, they changed the way you do HTTP requests.

Comment: Do what Targaryen said, if you're unsure throw in as much `console.log` as possible to see the flow. One thing I've noticed is you don't have any mechanism to get back `sections` data from service to your component, are you looking at the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used a service like that before. Maybe your implematation has a simple error, but here is how I always implement a service in angular. :)

## Service

```
getSomething() {
    return this.http.get('your-api-url').map(res => {
       return res.json()
    });
}
```

## Component

```
makeRequest() {
    this.service.getSomething().subscribe(data => {
        this.variable = data;
    }, err => {
        console.log("error :/");
    });
}
```